# aws - how to query a user with user's characters from the user's first or last name?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

so I have this app and I'm trying to implement a search bar, where if they type "Jo" I call a lambda function and it queries me the user: "John Smith" from my user's table. I have made a findRivalTable, where, for each player that's created, I create 2 objects. Each object has a key: firstTwoLetters, which contains the firstTwo letters of the first OR last name. The second key is the first OR last name of the user with the user's ID.

I've attached a picture of the table below to make it more clear. I don't know how to implement the "beginsWith" in the dynamoDB query. I have wrote the start of the query code in javascript but need help completing it. It takes the letters the user enters as INPUT, and then the query should return both of the objects in the table, which I can then query the user from my user's table.

```
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(); 
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) 
{
    completeCount = 0;
    completeCeiling = 2;

    function findPlayer() 
    {
        var params = {
            TableName:"Z_DEV_findPlayerTable",
            Key:{
                "firstLetters": event.inputCharacters
            },
        };

        dynamodb.update(params, function(err, data) 
        { if (err) {
            console.log("break 1A")
                console.log(err, "findPLayer error");
                callback(err);
            } else {
                console.log("break 1B");
                completeCount++;
                if (completeCount === completeCeiling) {
                    //cool we have the player! Now lets do a second 
                      query from the user's table from the ID we just got
                }

            }
        });
    }   


};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! So this is the syntax for:

1. User types in "Jo" for John Smith, when there are multiple John Smiths in your database. You need to pass in two variables.

a. first two letters of what they typed.

b. the whole string of what they typed.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) 
{
    completeCount = 0;
    completeCeiling = 1;

    var returnArray = {
    }

    findPlayer();

    function findPlayer() 
    {
        var params = 
        {
            TableName : "Z_DEV_findPlayerTable",
            KeyConditions: 
            {
                "firstLetters": {
                    ComparisonOperator: 'EQ',
                    AttributeValueList: [
                        event.first2Letters ]
                },
                "firstOrLastName": 
                {
                    ComparisonOperator: 'BEGINS_WITH',
                    AttributeValueList: [
                        event.currentTypedLetters ]
                }
            },
        };

        dynamodb.query(params, function(err, data) 
        { if (err) {
            console.log("break 1A")
                console.log(err, "findPLayer error");
                callback(err);
            } else {
                console.log("break 1B");
                console.log("my data is", data.Items);
                var folderKeys = Object.keys(data.Items);
                completeCeiling = folderKeys.length;
                for(i = 0; i < folderKeys.length; i++)
                {
                    var filteredPlayer = JSON.stringify(data.Items[folderKeys[i]].firstOrLastName);
                    var splitString = filteredPlayer.split('+');
                    var filteredID = splitString[1];
                    filteredID = filteredID.replace(/['"]+/g, '')

                    console.log("my filteredPlayer is ", filteredPlayer);
                    console.log("my filteredID2 is ", filteredID);
                    getPlayer(filteredID);
                }

            }
        });
    }

     function getPlayer(playerID) {

        var params = {
            TableName : "Z_DEV_playerTable",
            Key: {
                "playerID": playerID
            },
        };
        dynamodb.get(params, function(err, data)
            { if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log("break 2A");
            } else 
            {
                console.log("break 2B");
                //console.log("my data.Item is ",data.Item)
                if(data.Item != undefined)
                {
                    returnArray[playerID] = data.Item
                    completeCount++;
                    console.log("completeCount is " + completeCount);
                    if (completeCount === completeCeiling) 
                    {
                        callback(null, JSON.stringify(returnArray)); 
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("player doesn't exist");
                }
            }
        });   
    }
};
```